# Why is live video stream not fluent while audio stream is normal when they are played by Flash RTMP Player after being encoded

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, media, h.264

My video stream is encoded with H.264, and audio stream is encoded with AAC. In fact, I get these streams by reading a file whose format is flv. I only decode video stream in order to get all video frames, then I do something by using ffmpeg before encoding them, such as change some pixels. At last I will push the video and audio stream to Crtmpserver. When I pull the live stream from this server, I find the video is not fluent but audio is normal. But when I change gop_size from 12 to 3, everything is OK. What reasons cause that problem, can anyone explain something to me?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Either the CPU, or the bandwidth is not sufficient for your usage. RTMP will always process audio before video. If ffmpeg, or the network is not able to keep up with the live stream, Video frames will be dropped. Because audio is so much smaller, and cheaper to encode, a very slow CPU or congested network will usually have no problems keeping up.

Comment: Thank you. What you said sounds reasonable. If I push a file with flv format, the live stream can be played normally.So I also suspect if there is something wrong with my video stream. Such as, key frames of video have bigger pts than predictive-coded pictures.In fact, I really find the pts of  video's key frames are usually smaller than some other kinds of frames in the same GOP.